# All my code in sublime text converted to tags and i cant reverse it

Tags: html, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I pressed something in Sublime Text 2 and I have no idea how to reverse it. All my code looks like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with an HTML document that is heavy on attributes, it can be helpful to hide everything but the element type. This is extremely useful when working with something like jQuery UI that have long class names, titles, data, etc.

To hide:

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (OS X)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (Windows/Linux)

To show again:

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (OS X)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> (Windows/Linux)

(that's the numeral <kbd>0</kbd>, not the letter <kbd>O</kbd>)